# Debian: unable to set up SELinux

Tags: debian, selinux

I'm trying to set up SELinux on Debian 6 according to  ([the instructions reported on the Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup#Steps_to_setup_SELinux)).

I've run this commands:

```
apt-get install selinux-basics selinux-policy-default 
selinux-activate
```

After reboot, the system should have taken a while to label the filesystems on boot and then rebooted a second time when that was complete.  However, neither labeling nor rebooting occurred.

The command:

```
check-selinux-installation
```

returns:

```
/usr/sbin/check-selinux-installation:19: DeprecationWarning: os.popen3 is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  @staticmethod
/usr/sbin/check-selinux-installation:23: DeprecationWarning: os.popen2 is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  def fix():
getfilecon:  getfilecon(/proc/1) failed
SELinux is not enabled.
Could not read the domain of PID 1.
/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled
FSCKFIX is not enabled - not serious, but could prevent system from booting...
```

This is strange because the kernel is SELinux-enabled, and the `grub.cfg` does contain the `selinux=1` option.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I've just uploaded selinux-basics 0.5.1 to Debian experimental. Could you please try with that version. But anyway, you could use `sestatus` to check the status of selinux on your system.

Answer (score 5):

Check `sestatus` if it returns `enabled` then it's working fine.

Also enter the command

```
grep FSC /etc/default/rcS
```

If it returns `#FSCKFIX=no` then use gedit or any other editing tool to edit the rcS file uncomment the line and set it to yes (like this `FSCKFIX=yes`) then save and exit gedit. 
After editing the file re-enter the command 
`grep FSC /etc/default/rcS` should return `FSCKFIX=yes`

if the command `check-selinux-installation` returns just

```
/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled
```

then it's fine and the above return is a false positive.
For editing grub.cfg and checking the audit; follow the steps given by  [Debian Wiki for SELinux Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup). Use linux with enhanced security ~ **SELinux**.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty late now, almost 9 years. But I did faced this error and the easiest solution I came up with is to update your OS version, I had Ubuntu 18.04 which installed selinux-basics version 0.5.6, as this issue was caused in version 0.5.6 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860522 due to  use of systemd.
This bug was solved just an year ago https://salsa.debian.org/selinux-team/selinux-basics/-/commit/5355b76eb6b3f100f93c7acb6121e72814c1e3d7 and must have been patched in version 0.5.7 as Ubuntu 20.04 installs this version.

Well I am not sure what caused the problem 9 years ago but based on the current situation I would recommend upgrading the OS version to at-least 20.04 if using Ubuntu.

Well if it helps do let me know.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install auditd`, you may lack this package.