# What's missing with my SELinux installation?

Tags: debian, selinux

According to [Introduction to SELinux](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.selinux.html), section 14.4.2,

> SELinux support is built into the standard kernels provided by Debian. The core Unix tools support SELinux without any modifications.

I have installed the `selinux-basics` and `selinux-policy-default` packages on my **Debian Wheezy** (*stable*) system, and I saw it loading some policies during the installation, so I'm pretty sure the installation itself went well.

I edited /etc/default/grub to say:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="selinux=1 audit=1 enforcing=0"
```

(that variable used to be empty) and ran update-grub. /boot/grub/grub.cfg does include the SELinux-related kernel parameters.

I created a file `/.autorelabel` based on the /usr/sbin/selinux-activate script's "enable" branch.

I have rebooted the system after making the above changes. Nothing out of the ordinary happened during that reboot.

`dmesg | head` outputs, among else:

```
Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513 ro selinux=1 audit=1 enforcing=0 quiet pci=nomsi
```

As far as I can tell, everything is in place. Yet, **it does not seem to be working.** `id -Z` returns:

```
$ id -Z
id: --context (-Z) works only on an SELinux-enabled kernel
$
```

[sestatus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48319/2465) gives:

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
#
```

[check-selinux-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102589/2465) gives:

```
# check-selinux-installation
getfilecon:  getfilecon(/proc/1) failed
SELinux is not enabled.
Could not read the domain of PID 1.
/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled
Postfix init script is syncing the chroots.
Postfix has chrooted service in master.cf
FSCKFIX is not enabled - not serious, but could prevent system from booting...
#
```

**What's missing for SELinux to be enabled on my system?**

Comment: did you run `selinux-activate` https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup

Comment: To use selinux in Debian see https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup  and confirm you did all these steps (install auditd and run `selinux-activate`). Also, what file system are you using? In my experience in running selinux, I HIGHLY suggest you run Fedora or RHEL (Centos/Scientific). selinux on Debian/Ubuntu/Arch can be problematic and is not supported as well on these distros.

Comment: @richard You may be on to something, it looks like `security=selinux` is also wanted. Going to give that a try.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ext4 root, ZFS for pretty much everything else.

Comment: Alright, you may need to do some manual configuration with zfs.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen No worries about that; it's an unusual enough setup that I'm *used* to everything not just quite working right out of the box.

Comment: @richard I think the `security=selinux` (judging by comparing what I had with what the `selinux-activate` script did) just might have been it. I also added `auditd` but am not sure if that was required or not; the missing kernel parameter would certainly explain why SELinux wasn't enabled on boot. If you'll write up a bit of a proper answer from your comment, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I can't write it up I know nothing about it. I just know how to find the documentation. Can you write your own answer.

Comment: I wonder if Debian just doesn't support SElinux any more.  I have the same problem, and can find no evidence that SElinux is even compiled into the kernel.  It's weird that the documentation mentions Jessie, but on an out-of-the-box installation, there appears to be no way to enable SElinux in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, you need to pass `security=selinux` parameter to kernel as well. On Debian systems, this  should be automatically added to grub configuration by `selinux-activate`.

Kernel [documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7876320f88802b22d4e2daf7eb027dd14175a0f8/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L4036) explains `security` parameter:

> [SECURITY] Choose a security module to enable at boot. If this boot parameter is not specified, only the first security module asking for security registration will be loaded. An invalid security module name will be treated as if no module has been chosen.

On Debian this is relevant, as Debian also supports AppArmor security module.